# Изменение записи в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных

Доброго времени суток! Проблема следующая - не работает изменение записи таблицы (удаление и добавление работает). Код следующий:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "Update ThemeTest set NameTheme = @NameTheme," +
                       "NumberQuestion = @NumberQuestion, Prim = @Prim " +
                       "where (Id_theme = @Id_theme);";

   cmd.Connection = conn2;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_theme", textBox3.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameTheme", textBox1.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberQuestion", numericUpDown1.Value);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prim", textBox2.Text);
   conn2.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn2.Close();
```

Измененные данные просто не сохраняются в БД, без каких либо ошибок. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Скорее записи в таблице со значением Id_theme равное значению textBox3.Text нет.  
Вы очень смело передаете значение TextBox-а. Какова вероятность, что пользователь не добавит начальные и конечные пробелы?

Comment: Делаю так потому что данный textbox обрабатывается программно, без вмешательства пользователя. Это поле скрытно и в него заносится код редактируемого id_theme.

Answer (score 1):

на мой взгляд проще использовать linq

```
    using(SomeLinqDataContext sl = new SomeLinqDataContext)
    {
         var v = sl.Table
              .Where(w => w.SomeColumn == someString)
              .Select(s => s)
              .First();
         if(v != null)
         {
              v.AnotherColumn = anotherString;
              sl.SubmitChanges();
         }
         else
         {
              throw new NotEmplementedException("not found");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если идентификатор Id_theme - число, то логичнее явно это указать. Сделать пару вызовов

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id_theme", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@Id_theme"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую это сделать.